# ssh to Linux hosts using a VPS without port forwading

Tags: linux, ssh, port-forwarding

I have many hosts behind home modems that I need to send commands to.

I know that it is possible to configure port forwarding on the modems and access to them through the specified port but it will put me in a lot of trouble(IP tracking of all hosts, configuring many types of modems to make them do port forwarding)

knowing that I have a server with a static public IP address, is there an alternative to make my hosts contact the server so I can send commands to them?

I also have the possibility to develop the a script that does this but it don't think that's a reliable/secure solution?

Answer (score 1):

Have the computers you manage connect to a VPN server.  Setup your VPN server to dynamically update a DNS entry for each client, or provide a static IP.  You do not need to adjust any or the default routes, you would just be using this VPN to provide a management interface on each system.

This is very easily using something like OpenVPN.

Another thing you could, and probably should do is look at setting up a configuration management tool like puppet/chef/etc.  So instead of 'sending commands', the configuration management agent would be pulling the information from your central system.

Comment: doesn't a VPN require a port to be forwarded?

Comment: Depends on the particular technology in use, and how your setup your VPN topology.  But it certainly isn't required in many situations.  I have boxes I give to customer that will work on any network as long as the network doesn't block one of the following for outbound (udp/1194, udp/53, tcp/80, tcp/443, or tcp/53).  The OpenVPN client on my boxes are configured to try each port.

Comment: What about the OpenVPN server you use? which one is it(if any) that doesn't require a port to be forwarded?

Comment: My OpenVPN server is on a system with a public address.  No forwards are filters required...

Comment: Makes sense. I guess though if he wants a VPS (I understand that to be a virtual machine running a server) then if his VM is behind virtual NAT he'd need the hypervisor to do port forwarding Virtualbox calls that port forwarding too  too. http://i.imgur.com/zyQCjaC.png